# Reading US Marine Muster roll

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2

number 438 Donald R. Petit, joined the US Marines on the 14th December, 1942. He was my father. He was a journalist and founder of the "boot" marine newspaper/magazine.

What does the rest of the information on his US Marine Corps Muster Roll mean?

16,jdfr ERD, 14Dec42,anl DHS Springfield, Mass.

Answer (score 2):

The 1940 Marine Corps Manual is available on [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6rUyseBYZwYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) and also on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/MarineManual1940-nsia).  Information for completing muster rolls is set out from page 229.

There is also a list of approved abbreviations, "*for use in muster rolls and other Marine Corps forms*", beginning on page 24.

---

From the list of approved abbreviations we see that:

- jdfr is "joined from"
- ERD is "Eastern Recruiting Division"
- "enl" is "enlist(ed)/enlistment"
- DHS is "District Headquarters Station (Recruiting)"

---

The heading at the top of that page of the muster roll states that it covered the recruits arriving at Parris Island, South Carolina, for period from 1 January to 31 January 1943 inclusive:

[image: Muster roll heading]

---

So we can say that Donald R. Petit enlisted on 14 December 1942 at the District Headquarters Station (Recruiting) in Springfield, Massachusetts.

He then joined [Marine Corps Recruit Depot, Parris Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Corps_Recruit_Depot_Parris_Island) on 16 January 1943 (from the Eastern Recruiting Division, where he enlisted).

Comment: Thank you so much for this information.